# How to use DirectX::Model with a custom DirectX::Effect

Tags: 3d, directx-11, directxtk

I'm using the DirectXToolKit. I created a model like this

```
m_Model = Model::CreateFromCMO(device, L"Content/Meshes/cube.cmo", *m_EffectFactory);
```

And I want to use a custom effect I created that inherited from DirectX::IEffect.

```
    m_ModelEffect = std::make_shared<UnlitEffect>(device);
```

However, DirectX::Model by default creates its own effects, meaning in order to use my own shaders, I have to replace them using

```
MeshPart::ModifyEffect(ID3D11Device* d3dDevice, std::shared_ptr<IEffect>& ieffect, bool isalpha);
```

I'm confused on how to send my effect to that function.

Here is the code I'm using now:

```
for(const auto& mesh : m_Model->meshes)
{
    for(const auto& part : mesh->meshParts)
    {
        part->ModifyEffect(device, &m_ModelEffect);
    }
}
```

However this causes this error  `initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`
Searching for that error gives me many solutions that involve changing the function signature to use a const reference but how the heck am I supposed to use the function as is without changing it? What's the proper way to pass an address of a shared_ptr?

Edit:
I got it to work using this code

```
m_ModelEffect = std::make_shared<UnlitEffect>(device);

m_Model = Model::CreateFromCMO(device, L"Content/Meshes/cube.cmo", *m_EffectFactory);
for(auto& mesh : m_Model->meshes)
{
    for(auto& part : mesh->meshParts)
    {
        part->ModifyEffect(device, m_ModelEffect);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide your own `IEffectFactory` class instance to the loader, and use that to directly create your custom effects.

You can also replace them as you are trying to do. The reason you are getting *initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue* is because you declared the `part` pointer to be **const** which means it cannot be modified.

Instead try:

```
for(auto& mesh : m_Model->meshes)
{
    for(auto& part : mesh->meshParts)
    {
        part->ModifyEffect(device, &m_ModelEffect);
    }
}
m_Model->Modified();
```

See [the wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Model)

Comment: I got it to work and I want to thank you. You're a diamond, mate. You pop up everywhere where people are asking about DirectX and your resources are invaluable to us newbies looking to learn graphics programming. Cheers